# Cracking 1000-password assignment from hashed file

Tags: password-cracking, brute-force, ubuntu, john-the-ripper, vmware

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 on VMWare, tool: John the ripper
The whole system is up-to-date

The file has 1000 hashed passwords. There are 40 rules provided, a small word list is provided to help crack part of the password. Length is from 1 to 8

Methods already used:
-single
-incremental
-wordlist with 40 rules provided

hashed-password list:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codepath/cyb101-vm-setup/main/Files/unit3/cp_leak.txt

rules:
None

Drop

JumboSingle

Single

Extra

Wordlist

Policy

NT

ShiftToggle

Multiword

PhrasePreprocess

Phrase

PhraseCaseOne

PhraseWrap

Split

OldOffice

o1

o2

o

i1

i2

i

oi

T9

best64

d3ad0ne

dive

InsidePro

T0XlC

rockyou-30000

specific

hashcat

passphrase-rule1

passphrase-rule2

OneRuleToRuleThemAll

OneRuleToRuleThemStill

Loopback

Single-Extra

Jumbo

All

I already cracked 311 passwords with my limited knowledge and provided resources. I am not sure how I should do next to crack the rest. I went through the document of JtR but it didn't help much and seemed outdated. Could somebody enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to the community. What steps have you already taken?